# why $I_n \subset G_\alpha$ contradicts $(b)?$

Tags: real-analysis

I have some confusion in **RUDIN** book Theorem $2.40$ :Every $k-$cell is compact

My confusion written in red colour given below

> Here is an outline of Rudin's proof(Theorem $2.40$):

> Every k-cell is compact.

> Proof. Let $I$ be a k-cell consisting of all points $x = (x_1, \dots, x_k)$ such that $a_j \leq x_j \leq b_j$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$. Put
> $\delta = \{ \sum\limits_1^k(b_j - a_j)^2\}^{1/2}$
> Then $|x-y| \leq \delta$ if $x, y \in I$.

> Suppose there is an open cover $\{G_\alpha \}$ which contains no finite subcover. Put $c_j = \frac{a_j + b_j}{2}$. The intervals $[a_j, c_j]$ and $[c_j, b_j]$ determine $2^k$ k-cells whose union is $I$. At least one of these subsets of $I$, say $I_1$, cannot be covered by any finite subcollection of $\{ G_\alpha \}$. So we begin again with the k-cell $I_1$ and subdivide further to achieve a sequence of k-cells such that

> $(a)$ $I \supset I_1 \supset I_2 \supset I_3 \supset \dots$

> $(b)$ $\color{red}{ I_n \text{is not covered by any finite subcollection of}\ G_\alpha}$

> $(c)$ If $x \in I_n$ and $y \in I_n$ then $|y-x| \leq 2^{-n}\delta$

> by $( a)$ and theorem $2.39$ , there is  a point $x^*$ which lie in every $I_n$. For some  $\alpha , x^* \in G_\alpha.$ Since $G_{\alpha}$ is open , there exist $r >0$ such that $|y-x^*|<r $ implies  that $y \in G_{\alpha}$.If $n$ is so large that $2^{-n} \delta < r$(there is such  an $n$ , for otherwise  $2^n \le \frac{\delta}{r}$ for all positive integr $n$ , which is  absurd  since $R$ is archimedean , then $(c)$ implies that  $\color{red}{I_n \subset G_{\alpha}}$ , which  $\color{red}{\text{contradict} (b)}$

This completes the  proof

**My doubt** : in b) it already said that $I_n$ is not covered by any finite subcollection of $G_{\alpha}$

This implies that  $I_n \subset \bigcup_{\alpha}G_{\alpha}$ doesn't have a finite subcover

Then why $I_n \subset G_\alpha$ contradicts $(b)?$

Answer (score 3):

Take  neighborhood $N_r(x^*) \subset G_\alpha$. If $n$ is large enough that $2^{-n}\delta < r$ then given $p \in I_n$ $|x^* - p | < 2^{-n}\delta < r \implies p \in N_r(x^*) \implies I_n \subset N_r(x^*)\subset G_\alpha$

Here $I_n \subset N_r(x^*)$ where  $N_r(x^*)$ is bounded open ball this implies that  $I_n $is covered  by a finite subcover   so it contradicts $(b)$

Comment: +1. If $n$ is large enough then $I_n$ is covered by a single member of $\{G_{\alpha}\}.$